# View webpage on SVN server

Tags: svn, web

Is there a way to view a website whose files are on an SVN repository? I just got a link like:

```
svn://www.server.com/repo_name/trunk/web
```

And I'd like to be able to see what the site looks like so I have a reference for when I'm going through the code. Can I do this without checking out the repo and running my own server? I can use that URL to browse the repo in my SVN client, but I can't get the files viewable in a browser.

Comment: What are the file extensions of the files you are looking at?

Comment: Have a look at [ViewVC](http://viewvc.org).

Comment: @JoeR It's a Wordpress site, so a bunch of .php, .js, .css, .html, etc.

Comment: @SameerSingh Close, but not quite. I need a tool to view the file contents (and render them like a browser would), or just a way to view the files at the `svn://` address. I am assuming that the svn server is also running a web server (but `http://servername.com` is pointing to a different server...the svn protocol is redirecting somewhere else I'm guessing).

Comment: Sounds like you need some sort of script to checkout the source, create a temporary server, and host the website in the server. I'm not aware of anything that would do this, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple tools that act as a Subversion *client* in a web browser. My favorite is [Sventon](http://sventon.org). Sventon is easy to setup, and is fast. But most importantly for me, Sventon doesn't have to be on my Subversion server because it doesn't have to use the `file:://` protocol and there is absolutely no chance it will mess up my Subversion repository.

If you use `http://` instead of `svn://` the Apache httpd Subversion server does allow you to see your files in a standard web browser, but it's merely a bit of icing on the cake. You can't do diffs, see the change log, and it's difficult to see earlier versions, or to download source files. Your best bet is to use something like Sventon to act as a full Subversion client on a web browser.

Sventon needs a [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) server, but that's really not too difficult to install. You'll also need port 8080 open (or another similar port), but that's no real problem either. You download Tomcat, run the startup script, and put the Sventon `svn.war` in the Tomcat `webapps` directory. It takes about 15 minutes to set everything up, and it can be located on any machine you choose, and not just your Subversion server (although it can if you so desire).

Comment: This issue is that I don't need an SVN client (I have Cornerstone for that), I need a way to view the file contents in a web browser without checking out the repo and hosting my own server. I know I can do that, but the option of just viewing the site (a wordpress installation) was presented to me, so I'd like to know how that's possible and how I can access it.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify. Sventon (and their ilk) are Web based client ***browsers***. That is, you don't checkout with them. Instead, you browse your repository with them. Sventon will allow you to do what you want (browse your repository layout) without having to check anything out. And, Sventon is fast too. Set it up, and it's up and running ready to ***browse*** your repository. As a plus, you can look at history and do diffs without having to do any checkouts. As a bonus, you don't even need direct access to the server. I setup Sventon on my PC just so I can browse open source repos.

Comment: I don't want to browse the repo. I want to view the files in the repository rendered in the browser (Chrome, FF, etc). For example, when I open a .html file, I don't want to see the source for the page, but I want to see the actual webpage rendered, including executed PHP, JS, CSS, etc.

Comment: That's a bit different. PHP is a SERVER SIDE process, so you need a httpd process using mod_php to render PHP pages. That's a deal breaker right there for what you want. The only way PHP will work is if you have your own server setup. You can view HTML files with embedded CSS and JS files without a server since these are client executed -- up to a point. If your CSS and JS references depend upon a virtual directory structure, you'll need a httpd server to serve up that structure. You really need a httpd server for anything more complex than basic html files with some JS and CSS tossed in.

Comment: So there's no possible server setup such that a machine hosting an svn repo can also serve up the files within that repo? Someone telling me to "go see the site at svn://server-name.com/repo-name/" is incorrect? I just want to make sure before calling that person out.

Comment: Not at all. No browser handles the `svn://` protocol. mod_svn handles `http://` and fudges things, so it can display the _source_ if you specify a Subversion `http://` URL. You want to display the rendered files. You certainly cannot do that with PHP files without a server since it has to be handled on the server side.

Comment: the link seems bad